# Consuming OData V4 from SAPUI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am trying to use OData V4 with SAPUI5. Although it seems quite straight forward, I am facing couple of issues.

I am using sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleFormToolbar sample from Demokit. Implemented a OData V4 service to display the data in the simple form.

Changes i have done in this app: 
1. manifest.json and 
2. Page.view.xml for Context Binding of form control 
3. Removed code reference to mockdata in controller and index.html

However, I am not able to get data with following errors:

```
2019-07-07 08:58:23.736110 Failed to update path /Suppliers(12345)/Country - **Error: Must not change a property before it has been read**

**Uncaught Error: Must not change a property before it has been read**
```

Another error is related batch mode. I have not implemented any batch processing in Odata impl.

```
2019-07-07 08:58:24.279114 **$batch failed** - Error: Network error
2019-07-07 08:58:24.281175 Failed to read path /Suppliers(12345) - Error: **HTTP request was not processed because $batch failed**
```

The code i am using is:

//manifest.json

```
{
    "_version": "1.12.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleFormToolbar",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "dataSources": {
          "supplierOData": {
            "uri": "https://supplierappp1014576trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/SupplierApp/SupplierService.svc/",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
              "odataVersion": "4.0"
            }
          }
        }
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleFormToolbar.Page",
            "type": "XML",
            "async": true
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.layout": {}
            }
        },
        "models": {
            "": {
                "dataSource": "supplierOData",
                "settings" : {
                    "synchronizationMode" : "None"
                }
            }
        },
        "config": {
            "sample": {
                "files": [
                    "Page.view.xml",
                    "Page.controller.js",
                    "manifest.json"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//Page.view.xml

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleFormToolbar.Page"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
        <f:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormToolbar"
            binding="{/Suppliers(12345)}"
            editable="true"
            layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
            labelSpanXL="4"
            labelSpanL="3"
            labelSpanM="4"
            labelSpanS="12"
            adjustLabelSpan="false"
            emptySpanXL="0"
            emptySpanL="4"
            emptySpanM="0"
            emptySpanS="0"
            columnsXL="2"
            columnsL="1"
            columnsM="1"
            singleContainerFullSize="false"
            ariaLabelledBy="Title1" >
            <f:toolbar>
                <Toolbar id="TB1">
                    <Title id="Title1" text="Address" level="H4" titleStyle="H4"/>
                    <ToolbarSpacer />
                    <Button icon="sap-icon://settings"/>
                    <Button icon="sap-icon://drop-down-list" />
                </Toolbar>
            </f:toolbar>
            <f:content>
                <Toolbar ariaLabelledBy="Title2">
                    <Title id="Title2" text="Office" level="H5" titleStyle="H5"/>
                    <ToolbarSpacer />
                    <Button icon="sap-icon://settings"/>
                </Toolbar>
                <Label text="Name" />
                <Input value="{SupplierName}" />
                <Label text="Street/No." />
                <Input value="{Street}">
                </Input>
                <Input value="{HouseNumber}">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="XL2 L1 M3 S4" />
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Label text="ZIP Code/City" />
                <Input value="{ZIPCode}">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="XL2 L1 M3 S4" />
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Input value="{City}" />
                <Label text="Country" />
                <Select id="country" selectedKey="{Country}">
                    <items>
                        <core:Item text="England" key="England"/>
                        <core:Item text="Germany" key="Germany"/>
                        <core:Item text="USA" key="USA"/>
                    </items>
                </Select>
                <Toolbar ariaLabelledBy="Title3">
                    <Title id="Title3" text="Online" level="H5" titleStyle="H5"/>
                    <ToolbarSpacer />
                    <Button icon="sap-icon://settings"/>
                </Toolbar>
                <Label text="Web" />
                <Input value="{Url}" type="Url" />
                <Label text="Twitter" />
                <Input value="{Twitter}" />
            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>
    </VBox>
</mvc:View>
```

//Page.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
        'jquery.sap.global',
        'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
        'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel',
        'sap/ui/model/odata/v4/ODataModel'
    ], function(jQuery, Controller, JSONModel, ODataModel) {
    "use strict";

    var PageController = Controller.extend("sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleFormToolbar.Page", {

        onInit: function (oEvent) {
            console.log("hello");

            jQuery.get({
                url: "/SupplierService/SupplierService.svc/Suppliers(12345)",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log( "Recieved data: " + data);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    // your error logic
                    console.log("Error while requesting odata: " + error);
                }
            });


        }

    });


    return PageController;

});
```

//index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fullscreen – with toolbar</title>

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
            "sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleFormToolbar": "./",
            "sap.ui.demo.mock": "mockdata"
        }'
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
        data-sap-ui-async="true"
        data-sap-ui-preload=""
        data-sap-ui-frameOptions="trusted"
        data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport">
    </script>
</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
    <div data-sap-ui-component
        data-name="sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleFormToolbar"
        data-height="100%"
        data-id="container"
        data-settings='{"id" : "sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleFormToolbar"}'
        style="height: 100%">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added jquery call just to see if the odata is working or not.

Command used for CORS issue: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp

I am actually pointing to odata service in the same project. The same is deployed on Sap Cloud: https://supplierappp1014576trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/SupplierApp/SupplierService.svc/

Thanks for your time.

- EDIT:

Added the solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The error:

  "must not change a property before it has been read" is understood to be ***CORS issue***.
  Accepting Cross origin requests on server side can be done by configuring web.xml. Note that this should be re-evaluated for production use.

> ```
> <filter>
>           <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
>           <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
>       </filter>
>       <filter-mapping>
>           <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
>           <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
>       </filter-mapping>
> ```

- The error:

  "$batch failed - Error: Network error" is resolved by changing ***groupId to $direct***. This means we are sending individual network calls to odata service.

---

```
"models": {
            "": {
                "dataSource": "supplierOData",
                "settings" : {
                    "synchronizationMode" : "None",
                    "groupId": "$direct"
                }
            }
        },
```

---

This took away those errors and I see the data is rendered into form fields.

Thanks for your attention.